# How do you use XADD to increment a value in memory?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, mutex, atomic

I am trying to write a simple interface to atomically increment some value. I try to do the following (in C)

```
void foo()
{
    int counter = 0;
    assembly_xadd(&counter);
    printf("counter is %d\n");
}
```

> > counter is 0

Here is my code in assembly I am not sure if I am properly using xadd:

```
.global assembly_xadd

assembly_xadd:

    PUSHL %ebp
    MOVL %esp,%ebp
    PUSHL %edi  

    MOVL $0x1,%eax                                                    
    MOVL 0x8(%ebp),%edi                                               
    XADDL  %edi,%eax                             

    MOVL %edi,%eax    

    POPL %edi
    MOVL %ebp,%esp
    POPL %ebp
    RET
```

Comment: Um, doesn't it look odd to you that `xadd` in your code does not reference any memory?

Comment: i pass it the first argument which is the address where an integer is stored. this is in the line
>>MOVL 0x8(%ebp),%edi

Comment: So what? Your `xadd` still adds `edi` to `eax`, just registers, and the sum (in `eax`) isn't written to the memory. And then, even if it was, the purpose of `xadd` would still be defeated as `xadd` needs to add to a memory operand directly, if you want to modify it atomically. Finally, you'll need a `lock` prefix on `xadd`.

Comment: How then, could i give to the dest operand the address to the int without xadd interpreting it as the register literal value?

Comment: Doesn't `MOVL 0x8(%ebp),%edi` do it?

Comment: Check your CRT and compiler docs.  It ought to have an intrinsic for that, something with a name like InterlockedIncrement or __sync_fetch_and_add

Comment: I'm not seeing any parenthesis on the line with `xadd`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `XADDL %eax, (%edi)`. Remember with gas syntax the destination is always the second value, and that you want to alter the memory at address `%edi`. You are instead adding one to the address `%edi` and storing it in %eax. In genearl, `xadd` with two registers is useless (atomic memory access wise), as register operations are always atomic.

What you are doing with the `MOVL 0x8(%ebp),%edi` is moving the address of the 32-bit integer to `%edi`. Also, if you want to return the original value, which is what I assume `MOVL %edi,%eax`, is for, you shouldn't do `MOVL %edi,%eax`. `%eax` already contains the previous value of `(%edi)`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the atomic variable implementation in the Linux kernel, at [`include/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic.h`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=arch/x86/include/asm/atomic.h;h=722aa3b0462448fc5442cd4c72a485fc23cbf5f8;hb=HEAD) (the link is to the version in 3.8-rc7)

Answer (score 0):

xadd is implemented [here](https://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=arch/x86/include/asm/cmpxchg.h;h=8d871eaddb6677d7fccad7972593b7f36b81617c;hb=HEAD) in inline assembler.

You probably want inline unless your whole program is assembly, since even the code space overhead for calling a separate function is greater than the space taken up by xadd.  If you're writing your whole program in assembly (because of masochism? unreasonable space constraints?) you'll probably want to just use xadd directly.  Of course, there are a few instances where the assembly function is a reasonable idea, like if you want to link it into Perl or Python code, for example (but that in itself could have dangerous consequences if you're not very, very careful), or if you need to pass a function pointer somewhere.  But even then, I'd implement the inline assembler and then create the function part in C.